# Where to get the rpm for iptables-extensions?

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7

I want to have UDP load balancer, which seems to achieved from iptables from this [post](https://www.webair.com/community/simple-stateful-load-balancer-with-iptables-and-nat/)

I run this command which resulted in error as shown below.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i em1 --dport 9998 --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xx.xx.xx:9998
```

Output :

```
iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--mode"
```

I have also installed the ipset package,

> yum install ipset

How to install the iptables-module which has --mode option ?,  from the [man](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) pages, seems like i need to install statistic module but could not find out the tar/rpm file.

Comment: No one to answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Except for "protocol" modules (tcp, udp, icmp...) you have to explicitely state the module to which belongs the option. So after a look at "man iptables-extensions" --mode nth is indeed described under the statistic module. That means you just have to add `-m statistic` before its options.

try:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i em1 --dport 9998 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xx.xx.xx:9998
```